# zend form how to add lots of custom html

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-element

I have lots of zend_form, and I want to add lots of custom html in them, what are the possible options. For e.g. I have a page where user can attach multiple emails with the account, so I have a field to add new email address and on top of that I want to show add other email addresses user has attached with the account. To display a form field I am using decorators and generating following html
          `< div>

                <  label for="accountDetailsForm-email" class="required">Email:< /label>

                <  input type="text" name="accountDetailsForm[email]"   id="accountDetailsForm-email" value="" class="inputText" size="47" />

            <  /div>`
to display the uneditable data I want to generate
                  `< dl>

                        < dt class="required" >Email: < /dt>

                        < dd >user@email.com< /dd>

                    < /dl>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do.

The first is to write your own **form elements** and **decorators**, which I recommend if you want to reuse your code.

The the other thing is you can use e.g.

```
$form = $this->form;
echo $form->email->renderViewHelper ();
```

in the corresponding view file to customize your form, so do not call just

```
echo $form;
```

That would echo the form. But echo the elements manually  ;)